# How to create one css for every screen size even I cant change the className's in library

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I learn ReactJs and JavaScript and must ask how to set up this css best.

I use the [react-responsive](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive) to detect screen size and to set best layout.

My dilemma I have is this css:

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.navbar {
  transition: top 0.6s;
  opacity: 0.95;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.navbar--hidden {
  top: -150px;
}
```

That is the [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) `NavBar` and I need to create 3 different css versions like this:

```
.navbar-desktop {...   
.navbar-mobile {...  
.navbar-tablet {...
```

But when I do that the Navbar don't use the css since the `className` don't match css right??

What alternatives do I have here?
Hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: Do you mean media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @Ozone I must read about that how it works thanks. [I have this Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-design-with-react-forked-16lgi?file=/src/index.js) Basically it works ok as you see but if I insert a Navbar I can only style it once like setting the size of the Navbar toggler button. If screen change the button must be smaller right but the css is fixed like in css `.navbar-toggler-icon` , I need a way to set toggler button size when screen change but NavBar button only have this `className` `.navbar-toggler-icon`

Comment: I suggest you also check out some styling libraries like [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) to more easily define your styles with the components and handle nesting media queries, etc.

Comment: The NavBar have this toggler button (hamburger) with className `.navbar-toggler-icon` I can change the `height: 40px` in css. When screen gets smaller I want to set in css `height: 30px` . How do I do that? I use the `react-responsive` to detect screen is smaller but then how to set the height? The height is already set in css to `height: 40px`

Comment: Can I use many css files and load in the css for e.g. small screen when screen is small? and load in the css file for large screen when screen is lagre?

Comment: Thanks @Ozone media queries was the solution. Answer and I accept your asnwer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like css `media queries` are the answer to your question.

Read more about media queries on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries